# missing signature for supplied pubkey

Tags: signature, missing

Hi Guys I need help when I am trying to check Solana balance or address getting error missing signature for supplied Pubkey:......

I tried doing  Solana Config set -k

getting same error

Comment: Did you try doing `solana config set -k keypair.json`? Probably you might have forgot to add `.json` at the end

Comment: Yes @0xMukesh you are right i did same as you mentioned  above, can you please guide me what to do next

Comment: If everything ran successfully, you can check your Solana balance via `solana balance`. If the error still occurs, let me know. If you want to learn more about Solana CLI, then checkout the official Solana docs - https://docs.solana.com/cli

Comment: C:\Users\HP>solana balance
Error: Dynamic program error: No default signer found, run "solana-keygen new -o keypair.json" to create a new one

C:\Users\HP>solana address
Error: No default signer found, run "solana-keygen new -o keypair.json" to create a new one

Comment: @0xMukesh i tired  getting error